# yum install kernel source

Tags: fedora, yum, kernel

I'm installing dahdi on my Fedora 15 machine and when I try to build, I receive the following error

> You do not appear to have the sources for the 2.6.38.6-27.fc15.x86_64 kernel installed.

The problem is, I cannot find that kernel source anywhere!  yum provides kernel-devel*
gives me a couple of kernel versions older and newer than this version.  Does anybody know what the repository is for this kernel?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You neither need nor want the kernel source. Install the appropriate `kernel-devel` package (upgrading the current kernel first if required) and try building again.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, the kernel-devel package does not seem to exist..

Comment: It's definitely in the repos.

Comment: How did you find it?  yum provides kernel-devel* does not return it. Thanks

Comment: We use `list` to find packages by name, rather than `provides`. And don't forget to escape the wildcard.

Comment: [root@asterisk ~]# yum list available '*kernel-devel*'
Error: No matching Packages to list

Comment: I probably don't have the right repos

Comment: The kernel devel for your current kernel can be determined by: `kernel-devel-\`uname -r\``

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the mirror you were using (or yum had selected) was incomplete?  I see your kernel-devel package here:

https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kernel/2.6.38.6/27.fc15/x86_64/

To get it manually (may use "curl" instead of "wget"):

```
wget https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org/packages/kernel/2.6.38.6/27.fc15/x86_64/kernel-devel-2.6.38.6-27.fc15.x86_64.rpm
rpm -U kernel-devel-2.6.38.6-27.fc15.x86_64.rpm
rm kernel-devel-2.6.38.6-27.fc15.x86_64.rpm -fv
```